# Merge Image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, image-manipulation

Is it possible to merge pictures using javascript?

For example, if you have 2 rectangle .jpg or .png images files of the same size, is it possible that you can align it side by side and produce a merged copy of the two in a new .jpg or .png image file?

Answer (score 75):

You can use JavaScript to 'merge' them into one canvas, and convert that canvas to image.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var imageObj1 = new Image();
var imageObj2 = new Image();
imageObj1.src = "1.png"
imageObj1.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 328, 526);
   imageObj2.src = "2.png";
   imageObj2.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, 15, 85, 300, 300);
      var img = c.toDataURL("image/png");
      document.write('<img src="' + img + '" width="328" height="526"/>');
   }
};
```

Due to security, your two images must be on the same domain with your JavaScript file (i.e `http://123.com/1.png`, `http://123.com/2.png` and `http://123.com/script.js`) otherwise the function `toDataURL()` will raise an error.

Comment: example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ashleedawg/pen/XWdYXbw)

Answer (score 27):

Updating this for **2019/2020+**: there's an awesome npm package for this called [`merge-images`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images)

And its usage is very simple!

```
import mergeImages from 'merge-images';
 
mergeImages(['/body.png', '/eyes.png', '/mouth.png'])
  .then(b64 => document.querySelector('img').src = b64);
  // data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...
```

You can further customize it with positioning, opacity (both per-image) and the output's dimensions!

(I'm not related to this package in any way, I just wasted 3 days getting `html2canvas` to work and then found this lifesaver!)

Comment: is there a version of pure js without using node.js?

Comment: @lovechillcool you can use the `merge-images` package in the browser as well. If you don't have `npm` available, you can include it via a script tag: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/merge-images"></script>` - Node.js is not a requirement here.

Comment: I tried already. But kept getting errors of CORS

Comment: I wish i could pass base64 image into the sources array .....My webcam functionality would be much better, i guess.

Comment: wow! This library saved my life.

Comment: @kano Great library, this is what I am looking for, May I know how to save the merged image into a folder? there is no documentation on saving images.

Comment: @RSD does this answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58823267/2803743

Answer (score 11):

Huỳnh Quốc Phong is partially right:

You can use Canvas to merge images. But they can origin from other domains. Just load the pictures in your dom .
Once the pictures are loaded (can be checked with javascript, see below) you can use them in your canvas.

```
var canvas = canvasBuild.getContext('canvasObj');
var img = document.getElementById('mergePic1');
canvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

To check if the images were loaded, I would recommend using the jQuery plugin http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/ - but it can also be done without.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post, but I ran across it searching for a solution to this question, myself. Even moreso, I wanted to be able to upload the images that should be used (without needing to rely on server-side logic).

I've created a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/davidwalton/4pjreyfb/6/
) that builds on this:

[How to make a simple image upload using Javascript/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087076/how-to-make-a-simple-image-upload-using-javascript-html/45931408#comment33499540_22087076)

I then added Huỳnh Quốc Phong's logic above ([Merge Image using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765370/merge-image-using-javascript/15620872#15620872)):

HTML:

```
<input class="file1" type="file" data-image-selector=".image1" />
<input class="file2" type="file" data-image-selector=".image2" />
<br />
<img class="image1 hidden" alt="medium image 1" />
<img class="image2 hidden" alt="medium image 2" />
<br />
<input class="btn-merge" type="button" value="Merge!" />
<br />
<img class="merged-image hidden" alt="merged image" />
<canvas id="canvas" class="hidden"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
$('.file1, .file2').on('change', function() {
  var reader = new FileReader(),
    imageSelector = $(this).data('image-selector');

  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      imageIsLoaded(e, imageSelector)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});

$('.btn-merge').on('click', merge);

function imageIsLoaded(e, imageSelector) {
  $(imageSelector).attr('src', e.target.result);
  $(imageSelector).removeClass('hidden');
};

function merge() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    imageObj1 = new Image(),
    imageObj2 = new Image();

  imageObj1.src = $('.image1').attr('src');
  imageObj1.onload = function() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 328, 526);
    imageObj2.src = $('.image2').attr('src');;
    imageObj2.onload = function() {
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
      ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, 15, 85, 300, 300);
      var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      $('.merged-image').attr('src', img);
      $('.merged-image').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  };
}
```

Additionally, it incorporates a bit of transparency just to allow for two jpegs to be utilized.

Note that all image positioning & sizing is managed via the `ctx.drawImage()` functions. The demo will be ugly, but it should prove the concept. :)

Hopefully this is helpful!