# How to upload multiple images one singel time on single button by pressing CTRL key

Tags: c#, php, vb.net

How to upload multiple images one singel time on single button by pressing CTRL key.
Iam trying for multiple upload in one time in html and php by pressing CTRL key while clicking the files to upload?
html code:

```
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form action="multiple_upload_ac.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td><strong>multiple Files Upload </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Select file
<input name="ufile[]" type="file" id="ufile[]" size="50" multiple="multiple" /></td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

php code:

```
$path1= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];
    $path2= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];
    $path3= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][2];

    copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $path1);
    copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][1], $path2);
    copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][2], $path3);

echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][0]."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][0]."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'][0]."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$path1\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
echo "<P>";

echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][1]."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][1]."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'][1]."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$path2\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
echo "<P>";

echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][2]."<BR/>";
echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][2]."<BR/>";
echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'][2]."<BR/>";
echo "<img src=\"$path3\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";

$filesize1=$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][0];
$filesize2=$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][1];
$filesize3=$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'][2];

if($filesize1 && $filesize2 && $filesize3 != 0)
{
echo "We have recieved your files";
}

else {
echo "ERROR.....";
}

if($filesize1==0) {
echo "There're something error in your first file";
echo "<BR />";
}

if($filesize2==0) {
echo "There're something error in your second file";
echo "<BR />";
}

if($filesize3==0) {
echo "There're something error in your third file";
echo "<BR />";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a simple image upload using Javascript/HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087076/how-to-make-a-simple-image-upload-using-javascript-html)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<!-- IMPORTANT:  FORM's enctype must be "multipart/form-data" -->
<form method="post" action="upload-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(count($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'] as $file) {

        //do your upload stuff here
        echo $file;

    }
}
```

From: http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload