# Let user upload an image into a database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image-uploading

I looked for this question, but I could not find it. Essentially, I have an html form and I want to let the user upload an image into a web database using JavaScript.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: __Yes__ There are ways....!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a simple image upload using Javascript/HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087076/how-to-make-a-simple-image-upload-using-javascript-html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a file input element, or if you're using AJAX use FormData.

As an aside, typically once you get the file to the server, you only store the storage path in the db, the image itself is stored on disk; DB aren't particularly good at storing binary data.