# Why does this code work with querySelector and not getElementByClassName?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I was searching for a way to upload and preview and image with JavaScript and found this post : [make simple image preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087076/how-to-make-a-simple-image-upload-using-javascript-html).
now, I am a beginner JavaScript programmer and I wanted to know why when I tried to change the line `document.querySelector('img[class='preview']');` to `"document.getElementsByClass('preview')"` it didn't work.

from this:

```
function filePreview() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img[class="preview"]');
  var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function(){
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if(file){
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }else{
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

to this

```
function filePreview() {
  var preview = document.getElementsByClassName("preview");
  var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function(){
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if(file){
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }else{
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="uploadimg">
    <input type="file" onchange="filePreview()"><br>
    <img src="" height="300" class="preview" alt="Image preview"><br>
    <img src="" height="200" class="preview" alt="2"><br>
    <img src="" height="150" class="preview" alt="3">
  </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is make 3 previews (Big Medium and Small) by trying to set the image given by the input:file to all three image sources

Comment: It should be plural, `getElementsByClassName` in `document.getElementByClassName("preview");`

Comment: Notice the `s` in `getElement` **`s`** `ByClassName` in @j08691 comment

Comment: Still has issues with HTML Collection ,....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
document.getElementByClassName("preview");
```

And this will ALWAYS return an array of objects, thus, if you only have one DOMElement with a class of "preview", you'd need:

```
var preview = document.getElementByClassName("preview")[0];
```

You can read more about this method here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: I added previews [0] [1] [2] to the src reader line and to the else statement