# Image Upload Alerts with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been creating a blog website. All post images should be 800x800 resolution. On the admin page, when the author uploading image to post, if he/she will try to upload a bigger than 800x800 resolution, I want to show an alert to an author like a bootstrap danger alert. How can I do it?

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZECb.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FW2h.png)

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and share your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Not *completely* sure, but try creating it using `URL.createObjectURL()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL, [How to make a simple image upload using Javascript/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087076/how-to-make-a-simple-image-upload-using-javascript-html)), don't alter the image dimensions using css, insert the image into the page, and just get the image width and height.