# How to preview image before uploading in django

Tags: django, model, preview

I am trying to preview image before uploading it to the html page. I am using django. This is my model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
```

this is my form.py

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['image']
```

and this is my html page

```
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                
                        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                        
                        
                        <div class="fieldWrapper">
                            {{ form.image.errors }}
                            <br>
                            <label for="{{ form.image.id_for_label }}"><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Image: &nbsp;</label>
                            {{ form.image }}
                       </div>
                       <div class="field">
                            <div class="control" style="margin-bottom: 3%">
                                <button class="btn btn-theme" style="float:right;">SUBMIT</button>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                       </form>
```

I am able to upload and display the image in the html page but i want it so that before i upload i can see the image i am trying to upload. How can i do that?

Comment: for this feature you can only use front-end tools like js in your template: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: that doesnt work because it onchanging in input but my {{form.image}} already is uploading the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to upload an image for the first time, you can use createObjectURL, which takes the object present in HTML File upload.

```
<Image id="imagePreviewOne" thumbnail src="URL.createObjectURL(--get image object using selector--)"/>
```

If you are previewing images already present in Django models, then you have to use URL of the image in Image HTML tag.

```
<Image id="imagePreviewTwo" thumbnail src="URL to image present in django models" />
```

CreateObjectURL : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

File Upload: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_file_upload_button.asp

Comment: CreatObjectURL works if i do
                            <input accept="image/*" type="file" id="files" />
                            <img id="image" />
                            <script>
                                document.getElementById('files').onchange = function ()
                                 {
                                    var src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])
                                    document.getElementById('image').src = src
                                }   
                            </script>
But then i cannot save that data

Comment: Try this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087076/how-to-make-a-simple-image-upload-using-javascript-html

Comment: still doesn't work