# Overlay two images to one img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

The following question
[Merge Image using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765370/merge-image-using-javascript/17697784)
has some good answers to it. 
But the answers only have javascript and not the html context where they are in.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var imageObj1 = new Image();
var imageObj2 = new Image();
imageObj1.src = "1.png"
imageObj1.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 328, 526);
    imageObj2.src = "2.png";
    imageObj2.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, 15, 85, 300, 300);
        var img = c.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.write('<img src="' + img + '" width="328" height="526"/>');
    }
};

var canvas = canvasBuild.getContext('canvasObj');
var img = document.getElementById('mergePic1');
canvas.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

What would be a full working example with the html code?

Comment: The HTML would literally just be `<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>`

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an error on "todataURL"  Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported. on line 12

Comment: It sounds like the images you're placing in the canvas are not hosted on your own domain - hence the security warning. You need to host the images on the same domain that the canvas is running on.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your help so far. How would I load the external images into my DOM, so I can use them in my canvas?

Comment: I don't believe you can - it's a browser level security restriction. You need to host them yourself.